# SignalR connected client in Clients.User(..) shouldn't exist

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

In my SignalR hub, I use the following method to check whether a user has an active connection:

```
var receivingClient = Clients.User(receiver);

        if (receivingClient != null)
        {
```

But I also track the online users manually over `OnConnected` \ `OnDisconnected` (in a `ConcurrentDictionary`). Now even when I shut down everything and start the server from scratch (e.g. IISExpress from VS), the above code part returns a result for a connection that doesn't exist.
Let's say I send from User A to user B. I start the server, go online with user A, then send a message to B: The above code returns a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.UserProxy<mySite.Services.ChatHub>`.

I don't get it. Is it wrong to check for existing client connections with a null check? Should I exclusively rely on my manual tracking?

Thanks for some insight!

(PS: This is all on the same server - no load balancing / sharding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Clients.User(receiver)` returns a type that is used to invoke methods for the given user. It doesn't have anything to do with whether the user you pass in exists or not.

> Is it wrong to check for existing client connections with a null check? Should I exclusively rely on my manual tracking?

Yes. Use manual tracking.